# Create TableView in Xamarin C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, tableview

Refer to the code below, may I know what does it mean ...
When I copy to my xml project of visual studio, it is error.

```
Content = new TableView {
    Root = new TableRoot {
        new TableSection...
    },
    Intent = TableIntent.Settings
};
```

Comment: Please provide more code and information. Are you trying to create a TableView in a XamarinForms project? No xaml, just code behind?

Comment: Looks like that is from this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview There is a sample you can download that can help you see the full set up and where the code goes.

Comment: @VVVoon It seems that your issue had been solved.Why you did not mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are replicating the Example in Xamarin Page. The errors you are facing, is that you are not creating the ViewCell for the TableView.

Here is a working example that should get you started.

```
var table = new TableView();
table.Intent = TableIntent.Settings;
var layout = new StackLayout() { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal };
layout.Children.Add (new Label() {
    Text = "TestLayout",
    TextColor = Color.FromHex("#f35e20"),
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
});

table.Root = new TableRoot () {
    new TableSection("Getting Started") {
        new ViewCell() {View = layout}
    }
};

Content = table;
```

Comment: @VVVoon glad it worked. Don't forget to mark answer as correct and upvote :D